# Learning TypeScript with no JavaScript Background

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, typescript

I'm planning to learn `TypeScript`, I have enough `HTML5`, `CSS` basics, my problem is that I practically never used nor learned `JavaScript`, how bad is that, should I start learning JavaScript first, or I can just jump with TypeScript ?

Comment: I'd start from JavaScript.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The closest equivalence you might be more familiar with is trying to learn C++ without knowing C first. TypeScript while based on JavaScript and compiled to JavaScript is a different language which emphasises different aspects of programming than JavaScript.

Sure, a strong background in JavaScript would help you pick up TypeScript faster, but learning the basics of JavaScript won't do you much good compared to just diving into TypeScript.

Comment: You suggest I can just go for TypeScript directly, no harm with that ??

Comment: @AymenDaoudi Exactly.

Comment: I agree with this. Typescript actually helped me learn JavaScript. It was like having "training wheels" for full dynamic typing.

Comment: I agree as well. I knew a little JavaScript (DOM manipulation, mostly) when I started learning TypeScript, but I was having a hell of a time trying to wrap my head around JavaScript architecture and design patterns (e.g. prototypal inheritance, MVC, etc). The great thing about TypeScript is that it's made to make all of that stuff easy. In other words, TypeScript allows you to start using advanced features of JavaScript without much experience with the JavaScript.

Comment: @BryceJohnson : thx very useful information and experience , I'll take that in consideration